# calling ajax only during accordian open

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, accordion

I have a accordian in my system, which fills the content by ajax.
in the present system it is mentioned in onClick event.
so the function call happens on the open and closing time.

i need to limit it only to the accordian open time.

Comment: on click i am calling a function. i need to check that particular accordion is open or not in that time. can yo provide me the code for that?

Comment: OP, for us to show you code, you need to show us code.  SO is for us to help you with your code, not to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see your specific code, but I can tell how I went about it and roughly explain...

```
$('.va-slice').bind("expand", function(evt) {
if (typeof $(evt.target).data('state') === 'undefined') {
     url = $(evt.target).find('.va-content').data("url");
    $(evt.target).find('.va-content').load(url);
    $(evt.target).data('state', 'expanded');    
} else {}
}).bind("collapse", function(evt) {$(evt.target).data('state', 'collapsed');                    
    }).toggle(function() { // toggle between 
        $(this).trigger("expand");
    }, function() {
        $(this).trigger("collapse");
});
```

each 'va-slice' basically contains a content area 'va-content', 
ive defined two events; expand and collapse.
on expanding, i check if the data 'state' has been set or not, 
if not then it is the first time this area has been clicked so i load the content then set its 'state' data to 'expanded'
if it has been set at all then i do nothing, since closed or not, the data has been loaded before into the content area.

Does that help?